# How to display the (extended) ASCII representation of a special character in PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am trying to decode this special character: "ß", if I use "ord()", I get "C3"

```
echo "ord hex--> "  . dechex(ord('ß'));
```

...but that doesn't look good; so i tried "bin2hex()", now I get "C39F" (what?).

```
echo "bin2hex --> " . bin2hex('ß');
```

By using an Extended ASCII Table from the Internet, i know that the correct hexadecimal value is "DF", so i now tried "hex2bin()", but that give me some unknown character like this: "�".

```
echo "hex2bin --> " . hex2bin('DF');
```

Is it possible to get the "DF" output?

Comment: ß is a unicode, not ascii in php. string(2) "ß" vs string(1) "a".

Comment: I'm pretty sure C39F is right, see http://graphemica.com/ß . Note that `ord` returns the integer value of the *first byte* of a string, and for "special" characters as you put it, this won't necessarily be the complete picture.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong: ß is 0x00DF in [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F): in UTF-8 that value is coded as `C39F`. Maybe was coded as A7 in some windows codepage or other crap like that but, likely for us, in modern times UTF-8 is the main encoding.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure where you're getting A7 from - that maps to `§`

Comment: *special character: "ß"* ... there is absolutely nothing special about that character btw - you could write it as *"ss"* if someone forced you to use ASCII for some reason. It's perfectly happy in Latin 8859-1, Windows-1252 (derived from 8859-1) and UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake, it is "DF", not "A7", the question is fixed!

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do with that hexadecimal representation, and are you sure you aren't better off keeping that UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Start here: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path with `bin2hex`, what you're confused about is merely the encoding. Currently you're seeing the hex value of ß for the UTF-8 encoding, because your string is encoded in UTF-8. What you want is the hex value for that string in some other encoding. Let's assume "Extended ASCII" refers to ISO-8859-1, as it colloquially often does (but doesn't have to):

```
echo bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', 'ß'));
```

Now, having said that, I have no idea what you'd use that information for. There are many valid "hex values" for the character ß in various different encodings; "Extended ASCII" is just one possible answer, and it's a vague answer to be sure, since "Extended ASCII" has very little practical meaning with hundreds of different "Extended ASCII" charsets available.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII goes from 0x00 to 0x7F. This is not enough to represent all the characters needed so historically old Windows OSes used the available space in a byte (from 0x80 to 0xFF) to represent different characters depending on the localization. This is what codepages are: an arbitrary mapping of non-ASCII values to non-ASCII characters. What you call "extended ASCII" is IMO an inappropriate name for a codepage.

The assumption 1 byte - 1 character is dead and (if not) must die.

So actually what you are seeing is the UTF-8 representation of `ß`. If you want to see the UNICODE code point value of `ß` (or any other character) just show its UTF-32 representation that AFAIK is mapped 1:1.

```
// Print 000000df
echo bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-32BE', 'ß')));
```

Answer (score 0):

`bin2hex()` should be fine, as long as you know what encoding you are using.

The `C3` output you get appears to be the first byte of the two-byte representation of the character in UTF-8 (what incidentally means that you've configured your editor to save files in such encoding, which is a good idea in 2017).

The [`ord()` function](http://php.net/ord) does not accept arbitrary encodings, let alone Unicode-compatible ones such as UTF-8:

> Returns the **ASCII** value of the first character of `string`.

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) (a fairly small 7-bit charset) does not have any encoding for the [`ß` character](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%C3%9F) (aka [U+00DF LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm)). Seriously. ASCII does not even have a `DF` position (it goes up to `7E`).

Comment: *"first character of string"*… I can see where the confusion comes from in a *one character string* like "ß"… :)

Comment: Extended ASCII goes up to "FF" technically! "C3" is not going to work for we because that maps to "Ã".

Comment: @cronos *Which* ["extended ASCII"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) exactly…?

Comment: @cronos Oh, you mean ISO-8859­-1.

Comment: Probably, extended ASCII is to ASCII what JavaScript is to Java.